# FullCalendar v5: How to make content width fit screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am currently building a calendar and timeline view with fullcalendar v5.
My customers want to have a month view where they can overlook the whole month at once, no scroll bars. I know you can set the contentHeight to auto, but there is no option for width.
My slotDuration is 1 day. This is a non-negotiable.

I'd like to do this responsively and not hardcode column widths in pixels.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't have an option for this in the timeline view - it's deliberately flexible to cope with the variability of slot durations, view durations etc. That's why it has the ability to scroll. If you have a sufficiently wide screen then you won't see scroll bars. Perhaps if you need this as a must-have and you need more control over it you can consider [making a feature request to fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) about it...you could even consider offering to contribute funding or coding expertise to speed up the development, I guess.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `width` as one of the following values :

```
width: fit-content;/*Will give width upto the content of calender can fit completely*/
width: max-content;/*Will give width upto the max-content of calender*/
width: 100%;/*Will give the full container width to calender*/
width: 100vw;/*Will give the full view-port width to the calender*/
```

Use this so that padding don't create extra space and lead to overflow :

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately.
fit-content makes the calendar width even smaller, somehow, but the content stays the same